# Finding parents of Maria Cima of Pontevedra, Galicia, Spain?

Tags: vital-records, parentage, spain

My great grandmother was Maria Cima:

- probably born in Pontevedra, Galicia, Spain in 1895
- married to Joaquin (I suppose it is his name) Rodriguez
- died in Argentina in 1950
- they had 3 children: Dolores (b 1902), Balbina (b 1895) and Pedro (1890-1950).

  - All lived in Cans, Porriño, Pontevedra and emigrate to Argentina without his spouse-father, who possibly dies in a Civil War.
  - Dolores returned to Spain with her spouse Efrain and died in Cans. She had no children.
  - Pedro (my grandfather) and Balbina died in Argentina. I have only information about the "Argentine step".

The last part of family story is clear and I have enough information, but from the Spain story I do not have more data than what I have described.

What records or resources can I use to determine Maria's parents and brothers and sisters (if she had any)?

Comment: I think what I would look for first is a death certificate or burial record for Dolores, in case that names (and thus confirms) his parents.  Perhaps you can make your question "Seeking death record for Dolores in Cans, Spain?"  What is missing from your question is any sort of time frame - can you add at least the year for any of the pieces of information that you have cited, please?  Please be aware that care must be taken with anyone born less than 100 years ago - see [help/on-topic] for our privacy policy.

Comment: Hi @PolyGeo. The information that I'd cited is the following:
Maria Cima:probably was born in Pontevedra, Spain in 1895 and married to Joaquin (I suppose it is his name) Rodriguez. She dies in Argentina in 1950.
They had 3 sons, Dolores (b 1902), Balbina (b 1895) and Pedro (1890-1950).
All lived in Cans, Porriño, Pontevedra and emigrate to Argentina without his spouse-father, that possible dies in a Civil War.
Dolores returned to Spain with her spouse Efrain and died in Cans. Pedro (my grandfather) and Balbina died in Argentina.. I have only information about "argentine step".

Comment: @PCR I'm still not very clear what you are looking for. You seem to know lots of facts about Maria and her children. Is your main goal to find where Maria was born, and her parents?

Comment: Hello @HarryVervet, I'm looking for Maria's parents and brothers and sisters (if she had yhwm), her husband born and desath with his parents, sisters amd brothers. All the information I have is from María to present, and I'm looking forward to complete my familiy tree and continue the investigation. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi, thank you for clarifying your question. I added it to the main question above using the [edit] button. I made this question specifically about Maria rather than her husband, because I think it makes sense for you to ask a separate question about Joaquin once you have got some answers about Maria.

Answer (score 3):

You can request [birth](https://sede.mjusticia.gob.es/eCertificados/CertificadoNacimiento.do?lang=en_gb&idtramite=1215327470593&idpagina=1215197884559), [marriage](https://sede.mjusticia.gob.es/eCertificados/CertificadoMatrimonio.do?lang=en_gb&idtramite=1215327470542&idpagina=1215197884559) and [death](https://sede.mjusticia.gob.es/eCertificados/CertificadoDefuncion.do?lang=en_gb&idtramite=1215327470343&idpagina=1215197884559) certificates to the Spanish Civil Registry. There are records since 1870.

In your case, you will find the Civil Registry of *O Porriño* under Galicia, Pontevedra.

The form has some mandatory fields like Tome, Page or Date of Event that you probably don't know. You can provide an approximate value for the Date and "Des" (*Desconocido* - unknown) for Tome and Page. For genealogical purposes the most appropriate *Type of Certificate* is *Literal*, an exact copy of the original record.

Comment: Hi, I have good news...  My research concluded that the mother's maiden name of Mary Cima is Carballido, and  the mother's maiden name of her husband Joaquin Rodriguez is Boulo or Bolo. Perhaps this helps to move forward with the investigation with your help. Thanks!

Comment: Does this website provide any search facility? I don't know the comarca in which my ancestor was born, though I do know the region and province.

Comment: Hi @Noldorin, I'm afraid you need more than just the region and the province. Requests on this website are sent to the Civil Registry of the specified municipality.

Comment: @gparis, Ah, that's a shame. They really need a centralised database! At least by region. Thanks for clarifying though.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to complete [@gparis answer](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/10562/19).

For getting the accessing the information from the spanish register: go to this website and request it: https://sede.mjusticia.gob.es/cs/Satellite/Sede/es/tramites

However the register is only allowing you going in the "up direction", given a person you can know the fathers, not the children, there are some exceptions in the death registers.

Do not know if they deliver outside Spain. Essentially you need to have name, surname, approximate born date and exact location (municipality).

If you know your ancestors died in a specific location try to look to the cemetery and contact the administrators. Some cemeteries are able to provide you exact location of your relative and the death record date. Also knowing the cemetery you might be able to know your relative buried in the same location...

Contact the local churches given they were catholics